# Problem decoding the output of regex {m,n} in sed

Tags: sed

I have created a file 'numbers.txt'

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

I was practicing the regular expression of the form {m,n} which refers to "at least m and at most n occurrences of the previous character".

Now when I use

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{1,3\}/ p' numbers.txt
```

it displays all the lines in the numbers.txt file.

However, when I use

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{1,3\}$/ p' numbers.txt
```

the command displays only those lines which have at least one and at most three characters.

Why is there a need to put this '$'? From what I have understood, putting a $ means that I am trying to find the lines that end in at least 1 and at most three characters.

Also, why is the first command printing all the lines?

Comment: It's easier to see what `^[0-9]\{1,3\}` matches if you run instead `sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,3\}/X/'`

Comment: "Do either of the Answers answer your question?" Yes they did...thanks

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression:

```
^[0-9]\{1,3\}
```

tells sed to look for:

- `^` - the beginning of the line, followed by
- `[0-9]` - a single digit, `\{1,3\}` - repeated 1 to 3 times, followed by
- anything or nothing

... which matches every line of your sample input, as you saw. It matches the first three lines because they start with one, two, or three digits. It matches the subsequent lines because they all start with 3 digits (and continue on, but the regex doesn't care).

Regular expressions are "greedy", meaning that by default, they will match as much as they can (given the all of the flexibility you encode into the entire regex), but also "lazy" in that they do not need to match the whole line unless you specifically anchor it to both ends with `^` and `$`.

Assuming your intention is to tell sed to only print lines that have *exactly* one-to-three digits, then you need to tell the regular expression that that's *all* you want to see on the entire line, which requires the ending anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Demystifying  the second case

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{1,3\}$/p' file
```

- The `^` matches the beginning of string
- `[0-9]\{1,3\}` allows one to three decimal digits
- `$` matches the end of string ( It is saying, okay i don't want anything more to the record)

Comparing with the first case the `$` makes the difference in the second.

Comment: And how does this explain why `^[0-9]\{1,3\}` matches all lines ?

Comment: @don_crissti : Will just add that shortly.. Kinda misread the question

Comment: was that $ really required in case I wanted the entire record?

Comment: @Snowbell  : In somecases you do. For example in case where you're looking for `^pattern$`. Here you need the entire record provided the *entire record* matches a pattern.